# boolean algebra: simplify $ a* b *d + \tilde a *\tilde c*d + b* \tilde c* d$

Tags: boolean-algebra

Simplify the following function(algebraically): 
$$y = a*b*d + \tilde a *\tilde c*d + b *\tilde c *d$$

the solution is: $$a*b*d + \tilde a * \tilde c * d$$ which i checked via karnaugh and also wolfram.

my "solution" so far: $b*d*(a + \tilde c) + (\tilde a * \tilde c * d)$ there should be a rule that should eliminate the $\tilde c$ inside the $(a +\tilde c)$ term. Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: So you have identified AND, OR and NOT, but what does $(abd)$ mean? $(a*b*d)$?

Comment: that's right, i forgot the "*"

Comment: So how about editing your question to put in the asterisks?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: write $$b*\tilde c*d = a*b*\tilde c*d + \tilde a*b*\tilde c*d$$ and then see if you can absorb

- $a*b*\tilde c*d$ into $a*b*d$
- and $\tilde a*b*\tilde c*d$ into $\tilde a*\tilde c*d$

using $x+ x*y = x*(1+y) = x*1 = x$ for suitable choices of $x$ and $y$.